# UITextView Will Not Scroll to Top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview, scrolltop

**Update** - I now believe this is due to me calling `[view.details scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];` too early--meaning before the constrains have been applied and layouts recalculated.

I figured this much out by calling the `scrollRangeToVisible` after the view was shown and *after* I took some action on the cell. (This would guarantee that all layout changes were complete before I made that call.)

Thus, what I need to know now is **Where should I make this call?** such that it occurs after the layouts?

**Original Post**
I've tried many solutions, but none of them seem to work.

I have a `UITextView` as a subview to a `UIView` -- a container for the text view plus a few other items. When a user clicks on a cell in a tableView, I pop up the `UIView` container to show more details--the full text.

Configuring the view, I set the `textView.text` value to my long string, I update the font, I set the color, and I show the container view. Unfortunately, it shows the text at the bottom of the textview rather than at the top.

I've tried the following solutions, to no avail--each one results in the same behavior as above: it still shows the text at the bottom of the textview.

Attempt 1: scrollRangeToVisible

- `[self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0,1)];`

Attempt 2: contentOffset (tried each of the following, but none work)

- `[self.textView setContentOffset:
  CGPointMake(0, -self.textView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];`
- `[self.textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.textView.contentOffset.x, 0)
  animated:YES];`
- `[self.textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.textView.contentSize.height-textView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];`

Am I fishing with those last items? Yes. I've run out of ideas. I've checked the values of `contentOffset.y` and `contentInset.y` -- both are zero.

I create the `UITextView` in a subclass of `UIView` called `PrayerPopupView`. Here's the process:

1. In my main `UIViewController` where the table exists, a user touches a cell. Based on this action...
2. I create an instance of `PrayerPopupView` in this view controller

   - In the creation of this view, the `UITextView` is created
   - The `textView.text` value is set.
   - I call `[self.details scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
3. I use a custom class (KLCPopup) to add the view to the `UIWindow` but I also tested by adding my `PrayerPopupView` directly as a subview of the view controller rather than using KLCPopup, just in case it mattered. Both yield the same result of text not scrolled to the top correctly.
4. Since adding the scrollRangeToVisible didn't work in the custom view itself, I also added it in the `UIViewController` before showing the `PrayerPopupView` (`[prayerPopupView.detailsTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];`), and still the same result.

Here's a screenshot of the view:
[image]

Here's a screenshot of the view properties in the debugger:
[image]

This shows the view hierarchy in the debugger: 
[image]

Comment: can u add a screenshot of your result ? Let's forget about textview offset for a moment.  Are you using constraints ? Did you check the textView frame in view debugger ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri - I added a screenshot. I did check the view in the debugger, and everything looks correct. Constraints are still right. The `_UITextContainerView` is the appropriate size, and when I "show clipped content" it's correct.

Comment: How and where do you create the `UITextView` and where do you make your `scrollRangeToVisible` call? I just tried something simple (manually create and populate a `UITextView` in response to a table row selection and insert as a subview of the View Controller's view) and it showed up with the text already scrolled to the top.

Comment: @BrentM - I added details in the original post to answer this, since I wanted to give a full description. I'm guessing it might have something to do with the way a view is configured, but I'm not sure what to look for.